# Unable to parse XML from file with ElementTree in Python 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm trying the module ElementTree of Python 3 to parse XML but I can't make it work.

I have a XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <show>
        <name>Name 1</name>
        <number>79</number>
    </show>
    <show>
        <name>Name 2</name>
        <number>382</number>
    </show>
</root>
```

And I want to check, given a name, if it exist on the XML and get the number. So when I write the code, I do:

```
    show_input = show.lower()
    file_to_parse = findXMLshowFile(show_input)
    file_path = os.path.join(LOCATION_URL, file_to_parse)
    root = etree.parse(file_path)
    shows = root.findall('show')
    for element in shows:
        name = element.find('name').text
        if name.lower() == show:
            show_name = name
            show_number = int(element.find('number').text)
            break
    return [show_name, show_number]
```

I get empty name and number. Debugging, when I do `shows = root.findall('show')` it has 2 objects but they are empty.

I'm reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements) and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Someone can tell me where it's my mistake?

Regards

Comment: at least, do `name.lower() == show_input` instead of `name.lower() == show`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I was so obfuscated that I did not realize, that was the mistaque. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RomanPerekhrest, I was doing everything right but I was checking the wrong variable.

Replacing `name.lower() == show:` with `name.lower() == show_input` was the solution.